# Variable printed the expected value but actually its value is different

Tags: linux, bash, escape-characters

The following syntax used in order to capture the word between `<Name>` in `.xml` file. I also use `xargs` to remove any spaces.

```
$> var=` find /tmp -name '*.xml' -exec sed -n 's/<Name>\([^<]*\)<\/Name>/\1/p' {} +  |  xargs `
$> echo $var
TOPIC
$>
```

Until now it seems to be OK. But `printf` shows something else:

```
$> printf "%q\n" "$var"
$'TOPIC\r'
$>
```

Let's drill down:

```
$> [[ TOPIC == $var ]] && echo they are equal
$>
```

**No "they are equal" ever printed.**

But when we echo `$var` we get:

```
$> echo $var
TOPIC
$>
```

The BIG BIG question is: how to remove the extra characters (`$`, `\r`) from the variable?

```
$'TOPIC\r'
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` is not in the variable, nor the literal `\r`. They are added to the output because you told `printf` to format this way: `%q`. The real extra character is "carriage return", code `0x0D`, which *escape sequence* is `\r`.

The root of your problem is your `.xml` files seem to use CR+LF line endings from the DOS/Windows world. See [this comparison on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications)

The document [*Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends) says:

> To simplify the tasks of applications, the XML processor must behave as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by translating both the two-character sequence `#xD #xA` and any `#xD` that is not followed by `#xA` to a single `#xA` character.

Here `#xD` denotes CR, `#xA` denotes LF.

In your case the whole `find … | xargs` statement is your XML processor (let's put problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348) aside). If you want to fully comply to the specification, you should pass every `.xml` file through `dos2unix` in the very first place.

But since the real problem is with the content of the variable, this may be enough in your case:

```
var=`find … | dos2unix | xargs`
```

If you don't have `dos2unix`, `tr -d '\r'` would work as a replacement in this context (thank you @GordonDavisson for pointing this out).

Comment: If you don't have `dos2unix`, `tr -d '\r'` would work as a replacement in this context.